# UDP NAT hole punching example

Tags: c++, udp, nat, hole-punching

I try search in google and here but i still cant find simple C\C++ example udp hole punching algorithm. Please help if you know where i can find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can browse this open source code for it:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/stunner.aspx

You should googled 'STUN'

Comment: Might also want to look up [TURN](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5766).